# What is the highest $n\in\Bbb N$ for which a complete classification of inverse semigroups of order up to $n$ is known?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

> What is the highest $n\in\Bbb N$ for which a complete classification of inverse semigroups of order up to $n$ is known?

Given that [there are $3{,}684{,}030{,}417$ semigroups of order $8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2235633/104041), I guess $n\le 8$.

A list of inverse semigroups of order up to $n$ would be nice.

---

EDIT: According to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001428), the number $a(m)$ of inverse semigroups of order $m$, considered to be equivalent when they are isomorphic or anti-isomorphic (by reversal of the operator), is

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
m& a(m)\\
\hline
1 & 1\\
2 & 2\\
3 & 5\\
4 & 16\\
5 & 52\\
6 & 208\\
7 & 911\\
8 & 4,637\\
9 & 26,422\\
10 & 169,163 \\
11 & 1,198,651 \\
12 & 9,324,047 \\
13 & 78,860,687 \\
14 & 719,606,005\\
15 & 7,035,514,642
\end{array}$$

Comment: Being isomorphic and anti-isomorphic are the same for inverse semigroups

Comment: You might look at https://profiles.shsu.edu/mem037/ISGs.html